# Параллельное программирование С++

Tags: c++, openmp

Задание было, написать программу и распараллелить ее, само задание звучит так : Задана последовательность, состоящая только из символов `>`, `<` и `-`. Требуется найти количество стрел, которые спрятаны в этой последовательности. Стрелы – это подстроки вида `>>-->` и `<--<<`.

Входные данные
В первой строке входного файла INPUT.TXT записана строка, состоящая из символов `>`, `<` и `-` (без пробелов). Строка состоит не более, чем из 250 символов.

Выходные данные
В единственную строку выходного файла OUTPUT.TXT нужно вывести искомое количество стрелок.

Программу я написал, но распараллелить не смог,аргументируя ,что дана последовательность, которую если разбив то можно потерять пару стрелок, сказали,что я не прав и что можно распараллелить , подскажите как это можно реализовать

Код программы

```c
include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

int f(string s) {
  int k = 0;
  string t;
  for (int i = 0; i <= int(s.size()) - 5; i++) {
    t = s.substr(i, 5);
    if (t == ">>-->" || t == "<--<<")
      k++;
  }
  return k;
}

int main() {
  ifstream in ("input.txt");
  ofstream out("output.txt");

  string s, t;
  int k;
  in >> s;

  k = f(s);
  out << k;
  cout << k;
  out.close();

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Напрашивается два потока - один ищет стрелы, направленные влево, второй - вправо...

Comment: Что?Можете подробно описать?

Answer (score 0):

У вас длина стрелы 5 символов. Разбиваете исходную строку на N блоков, причем следующий блок начинается за 4 символа до конца предыдущего. И каждый блок отдаете своему потоку

Comment: А в `>>-->>-->` - считается, что тут 2 строки или только одна?...

Comment: @Harry Это к ТС. Я бы считал, что одна. Из предположения, что один символ может принадлежать не более чем одной стреле